# Dictionaries with operator overloading

Tags: c#, dictionary, operator-overloading, .net-standard

I was wondering if i can make 2 dictionaries sum into one using operator overloading, but im far away of the right mode to do it, here is my code.

```
    class Program
    {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         int[] array1key = new int[] { 0, 1, 3, 7 };
         int[] array1values = new int[] { 5, 7, -3, 9 };

         int[] array2key = new int[] { 0, 2 };
         int[] array2values = new int[] { 2, 4 };

         Dictionary<int, int> Polinomio1 = new Dictionary<int, int>();
         Dictionary<int, int> Polinomio2 = new Dictionary<int, int>();

         for (int i = 0; i < array1key.Length; i++)
         {
             Polinomio1.Add(array1key[i], array1values[i]);
         }
         for (int i = 0; i < array2key.Length; i++)
         {
             Polinomio2.Add(array2key[i], array2values[i]);
         }
         Dictionary<int, int> Sumar = Polinomio1 + Polinomio2;
     }
   }
   class Polinomio
   {
   public Dictionary<int,int> Polinomio1 = new Dictionary<int,int>();
   public static Dictionary<int,int> operator + (Dictionary<int,int> 
   Polinomio1,Dictionary<int,int> Polinomio2)
   {
        return Polinomio1 + Polinomio2;
   }
   }
```

Comment: As the error message explains when you try to overload the operator, operator overloads must include at least one parameter that is of the same type as the class being passed in. You cannot generally overload `+` or any other operator on a class you didn't write. You can, of course, inherit that class and put your overload there. But of course that will work only when at least one of the operands is that derived class. Frankly, I'm skeptical of the value of overloading `+` for a dictionary; there is no single, obvious meaning for the operator. A well-named method would be much smarter.

Comment: Then how could I do it with methods?

Comment: What do you mean? You just write a method, with two parameters, one for each input dictionary. Do whatever it is in the method you think is the "sum" of the dictionaries, and return the result. Just like any other method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a complex situation but I can give you some idea and you may choose the best one for you.

> First you can not overload an operator if one of the parameters in
>   overloading parameter list is not the same type of the containing
>   class, so if you are in the class `Polinomio` you must provide one of the parameters of this type which is not want you want because you are looking to overload operator `+` for `Dictionary<>` class.
>   Refer to this question [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/172534/C-Operator-Overloading) what is the problem for containing class.

1. One way to solve this is issue is to inherit from `Dictionary<>` class itself. Lets see the example below to understand better what I mean.

   ```
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           //Made those in same size to not throw an exception
           int[] array1Key = new int[] { 0, 1, 3, 7 };
           int[] array1Values = new int[] { 5, 7, -3, 9 };

           int[] array2Key = new int[] { 0, 2, 3, 4 };
           int[] array2Values = new int[] { 2, 4, 4, 8 };

           //Create Polinomio object which will serve as `Dictionary<>` in this case
           Polinomio polinomio1 = new Polinomio();
           Polinomio polinomio2 = new Polinomio();

           for (int i = 0; i < array1Key.Length; i++)
           {
               polinomio1.Add(array1Key[i], array1Values[i]);
           }
           for (int i = 0; i < array2Key.Length; i++)
           {
               polinomio2.Add(array2Key[i], array2Values[i]);
           }
           Dictionary<int, int> sum = polinomio1 + polinomio2;
           for (int i = 0; i < sum.Count; i++)
           {
               Console.WriteLine($"{sum.Keys.ElementAt(i)} {sum.Values.ElementAt(1)}");
           }
           Console.ReadLine();
       }

   }
   public class Polinomio : Dictionary<int, int> //inheritance
   {
       public static Dictionary<int, int> operator +(Polinomio p1, Polinomio p2)
       {
           if (p1.Count != p2.Count)
           {
               throw new Exception("Not the same Size");
           }
           Dictionary<int, int> dictionaryTemp = new Dictionary<int, int>();
           for (int i = 0; i < p1.Count; i++)
           {
               dictionaryTemp.Add(p1.Keys.ElementAt(i) + p1.Keys.ElementAt(i), p1.Values.ElementAt(i) + p2.Values.ElementAt(1));
           }
           return dictionaryTemp;
       }
   }
   ```

   2. Another solution is to add an extension method to `Dictionary<>` class like below:

      ```
      public static Dictionary<int, int> Sum(this Dictionary<int, int> p1, Dictionary<int, int> p2) 
      {
         if (p1.Count != p2.Count)
         {
             throw new Exception("Not the same Size");
         }
         Dictionary<int, int> dictionaryTemp = new Dictionary<int, int>();
         for (int i = 0; i < p1.Count; i++)
         {
             dictionaryTemp.Add(p1.Keys.ElementAt(i) + p1.Keys.ElementAt(i), p1.Values.ElementAt(i) + p2.Values.ElementAt(1));
         }
         return dictionaryTemp;
      }
      ```

You can call it like below:

```
Dictionary<int, int> sum = polinomio1.Sum(polinomio2);
for (int i = 0; i < sum.Count; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"{sum.Keys.ElementAt(i)} {sum.Values.ElementAt(1)}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May i suggest this one :

```
    public static Dictionary<int, double> Addition(this Dictionary<int, double> p1, Dictionary<int, double> p2)
{
    if (p1.Count != p2.Count)
    {
        throw new Exception("Not the same Size");
    }
    Dictionary<int, double> dictionaryTemp = new Dictionary<int, double>();
    foreach(var key in p1.Keys)
    {
        dictionaryTemp.Add(key, p1[key] + p2[key]);
    }
    return dictionaryTemp;
}
```